# Cache busting using jquery ajax and wcf rest service

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, rest

I have a Rest service and i would like to consume it using jquery ajax. But i have a problem on ajax not loading the updated one because it stores the cache.

So after googling i have found that the possible solution to my problem is cache busting or adding `cache:false` on my code. Based from what i know it adds a ?_=time on the URL. But my concern is when i actually make a get request since GET request appends the Parameter to the URL will it affect? because i have this on my Rest

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet ( URITemplate = "getsomething/{parameter}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Sample GetSomething ( string parameter )
```

Do i have to alter my Rest if i were to enable cache busting? Thank you.

## UPDATE

How about PUT or POST Method? i know that PUT or POST doesn't append the parameter on the URL so i think it might work but do i still have to configure or alter my Rest service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache:false will only add the timestamp querystring to the URL, it *will not* affect your current querystring variables.

Comment: But my GET ajax structure is something like this. url:'http://blah.com/getsomething/' + encodeURI(parameter), will it not affect my current request?

Comment: I don't think it should. Why don't you go ahead and give it a try? Also, you cannot do a POST on a WCF web method which has a WebGet attribute.

Comment: yeah i know it should be WebInvoke. Thank you

Comment: Also my project is on phonegap and android just to let you know. :)